# Export DLLs classes and functions and import them into Win32 Application

Tags: c++, dllimport, dllexport

I have a dll with a class that define some methods and variables inside it. I marked it as

```
__declspec(dllexport)
```

and i imported the .h header inside a win32 application project in the same solution. I can use the functions but when I try to compile the project I have a lot of errors about external symbols not resolved. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read about the standard way of using macros for this very common task here: http://wiki.tcl.tk/8721

The basic idea is that you define a macro, say `MY_API` like so:

```
    #ifdef BUILD_MYAPI
    #    define MY_API __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
    #    define MY_API __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif
```

When you declare a function or a class in the header file you do this:

```
void MY_API myApiFunction(int x);
```

When you build your own dll which declares the body of the function, you add the definition of `BUILD_MYAPI` to the build. This makes all declerations to be `dllexport`
when you include the header from some other dll you don't add `BUILD_MYAPI` so the decelerations are `dllimport`
When compiling with visual studio, you can add a macro definition to the compilation without changing the source from project properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocesson -> Preprocessor definitions

Answer (score 2):

For the application where you want to *import* that class, you will need to mark the class as

```
__declspec(dllimport)
```

Instead of `dllexport`.

You must also make sure to link with the import library of the DLL (a .lib file).

Comment: I have the dll project and the win32 project under the same solution, I've added to the include path field the path to my dll project but i still have errors. Why?

Comment: Did you do the 2nd part of my answer (linking to the .lib)? Go to Project Dependencies, and make your EXE depend on the DLL, and this should be done for you.